# Access denied after Mariadb version upgrade

Tags: mariadb

I upgraded my mariadb from 10.1 to 10.9 pointing to same data directory (checked ownership of files also). But when I try to access the mysql instance with existing users from different hosts (which used to work before upgrade), I get:

```
mysql --host <hostname> --port <port> -uusername -p<pwd>
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'ip' (using password: YES)
```

I tried flushing privileges & reloading mysql but nothing worked.
When I see the user * db information in mysql.user & mysql.db tables, everything is same pre & post upgrade.
Though I am able to remotely access mysql using root user. But other user don't work.
Also there are some users which are created as a part of init script (used in --init-file={} while starting up mariadb), I am not able to access using those users also. Only root user is working.
Please help what can be the problem.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Do you connect to localhost or to an external server? Did you notice any errors when running mariadb_upgrade?

Comment: Did you check if user `username` exists in `mysql.global_priv` ?

Comment: @hobby_programmer it it were not in `mysql.global_priv` it would also not be visible in the `mysql.user` view.

Seeing the result of `SELECT * FROM mysql.global_priv WHERE user='username';` would still be of interest though.

Comment: Another idea: was the original server set up to use SSL/TLS?

Comment: Yes. the username is available in mysql.user with all the required permissions. It has % meaning access from any ip & access to the database also in mysql.db

Comment: Observing the same issue, access denied when using mariadb-flavored client and the same command line connects perfectly when using oracle/mysql client. Have you found any solutions?